# Manual casting of agents and accessing its parameter of type SelectOutputOut in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I understood that I can insert different types of agents in the same block by changing the agent type in the whole process to the generic `Agent` (works well thanks to Amy). [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG7DF.png)

But, I am stuck on how to get them out using a manual casting for the process `selectOutputIn1`. Each Agent type has a parameter called `p_new_location` with type `SelectOutputOut`.

### What I need help in

passing what is equivalent to `agent.p_new_location` if properly casted through `selectOutputIn1`.

### What I have tried

creating a function with manual casting:

```
if( agent instanceof Wife){
    return ((Wife)agent).p_new_location ;
} else if(agent instanceof Child_M){
    return ((Child_M)agent).p_new_location ;
} else if(agent instanceof Child_F){
    return ((Child_F)agent).p_new_location ;}
```

[how it looks with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmb8A.png)

Unfortunately, as you can see there is an error saying the method must return a result of type SelectOutputOut although it is already defined.

The parameter type in each class looks like exactly like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufZaS.png). And from inside the simulation, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP9hk.png) before passing the value and like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K0LV.png) after passing its value. Furthermore, **I noticed that the value of an uncommon parameter type like `SelectOutputOut`, is not showing during the simulation** [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k46vQ.png). As you can see parameters (`age`, `countDb` and `taken`) are all there with their values but, not `p_new_location`.

### The Solution

Thanks to Amy Again :)

> The compiler is seeing if / else if / else if. What if none of those are true? If your last else if is the only option, just change that to an else or put in appropriate code for what you want to do.

This is how the code looks like now

```
if( agent instanceof Wife){
    return ((Wife)agent).p_new_location ;
    } else if(agent instanceof Child_M){
        return ((Child_M)agent).p_new_location ;
    } else{
        return ((Child_F)agent).p_new_location ;}
```

Thanks inAdvance;

Comment: Please specify what problem you are actually having with your proposed code.

Comment: Amy Greer has great points above. As she stated you'll need to cast in the actions in order to access the specific properties. Before doing this, you'll need to check the object type. You may know this, but for the sake of others reading this the code is something like. if (agent instanceof Wife) { ( ( Wife ) agent ).aWifeFunctionCall(); }

Comment: Thanks for your help that's kind of you. I am facing a new issue now. hopefully not a wrong casting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AnyLogic can easily handle multiple agent types in a single process block.  A few things to keep in mind:

- Make sure the process block is set to handle a generic type "Agent" or the parent class of mother, father, child.
- Since you have multiple agent types flowing through the same blocks, you should be prepared to do some casting to get any class specific information.
- AnyLogic agents cannot be in more than one flowchart block at a time, even though they can be in many collections.  They can also be in NO flowchart blocks.  Before you send an agent to an enter block, you must first remove it from any other block it is in (if it is in one).  For example, if all you wives were in a queue, you would need to remove the wife agent from the queue before calling your enter.take( wife ) line of code.

Comment: Thank you for these very helpful points. I managed to get them in but, not out. Could you please help me if you know how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Can you verify that all your classes have the parameter p_new_location set to type SelectOutputOut?

Comment: Yes sure, please have a look at the new images. I am wondering if the parameter type SelectOutputOut is causing the problem?

Comment: Your method does not have a default return.  The compiler is seeing if / else if / else if.  What if none of those are true?  If your last else if is the only option, just change that to an else or put in appropriate code for what you want to do.

Comment: Also, you can create a class called "FamilyMember" and then have husband, wife, child extend that class.  If FamilyMember has p_new_location and your agent type flowing through is FamilyMember, instead of a generic agent, it should cut down on the amount of casting you have to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now, and I will consider your other advice.